# Android fragment onResume() refresh data

Tags: android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a Fragment A with a RecyclerView.

Fragment A populates the RecyclerView items (a list of users) from SQLite and displays it in the onCreateView() method, and it works fine.

When i go to Fragment B and add a new user and hit done, i go back to Fragment A, now i should "Refresh" the users list.

I tried achieving that through moving the code from onCreateView() to onResume(). But, i have no access to a view like i do on the onCreateView().

What do you think is the best approach on handling this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, at first I suppose you should update  data on your list, which one you give to your adapter. If that won't help, try to create new adapter and bind it with recyclerview  in your onResume() method.